# How to combine/merge two JSON files into one in ADF

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have 2 JSON files generated and stored in blob. The JSON files were generated through ADF. My customer wants to generate the file as a single one. Below are two JSON files generated .

FILE1:

```
{
        "CustomerGroups": [
            "XX"
        ],
        "DebtorCodes": [],
        "Materials": [
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44512777",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 72.0
            },
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44583888",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 169.0
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Pricelist XX"
},
```

FILE2:

```
{
        "CustomerGroups": [
            "YY"
        ],
        "DebtorCodes": [],
        "Materials": [
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44512344",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 72.0
            },
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44583455",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 169.0
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Pricelist YY"
},
```

Output expected in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "CustomerGroups": [
            "XX"
        ],
        "DebtorCodes": [],
        "Materials": [
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44512777",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 72.0
            },
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44583888",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 169.0
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Pricelist XX"
},
{
        "CustomerGroups": [
            "YY"
        ],
        "DebtorCodes": [],
        "Materials": [
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44512344",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 72.0
            },
            {
                "ArticleCode": "44583455",
                "ColorOverrule": "null",
                "DescriptionOverrule": "null",
                "PromotionPrice": null,
                "SalePrice": 169.0
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Pricelist YY"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy data can be used to merge the file, provided we use the prefix and file should be in same folder.

Comment: can you elaborate this answer more?